# Magick++ Link Error When Trying to use attribute

Tags: visual-studio-2017, magick++

Using the `Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition`, and proven `C++` code, I get a link error when trying to compile and link a Windows `C++` Form application.

I am trying to get the exif data from a jpeg image file using the Magick++ attribute approach but I get link errors LNK2028 and LNK2019 for the image object instance attribute. The version of ImageMagick is 6.9.3-7 compiled with the Magick++ headers. The operating system is Windows 10. I get the same issue when trying to use the latest Windows version of Image Magick similarly compiled.

The exif data are there via the Windows command line indentify -verbose filename.

The Magick++ methods that I am using such as read, quality, resize and write all link and work fine but the attribute does not - (standard string) extracted_data = image.attribute("exif:DateTime"); gives the link errors.

If I comment out the block of code that contains the image.attribute statement, the program compiles, links and executes OK.

On a separate Windows 7 PC the identical C++ code compiles, links and executes perfectly. On that PC the IDE is Visual Studio 2010 Express with ImageMagick 6.8.6.

Have tried different versions of ImageMagick as per the above.

```
Magick::InitializeMagick(NULL);
Magick::Image image;        // create an instance of the Magick::Image class
image.read(std_input_file_name);    // read the selected jpg file into the image object 
... develop the resize parameters (not shown)
image.resize(Magick::Geometry(int_output_width, int_output_height));
... the above works fine.
... but if I include:
std::string extracted_data, date_time_data;
extracted_data = image.attribute("exif:DateTimeOriginal");
... I get the linkage errors
```

There are no compile errors indicated.

I'm trying to get rid of the two linkage errors:
LNK2028
unresolved token (0A00079D) "public: class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __thiscall Magick::Image::attribute(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" (?attribute@Image@Magick@@$$FQAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V34@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall UseLIB::Form1::btnStart_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?btnStart_Click@Form1@UseLIB@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)

and LNK2019
unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __thiscall Magick::Image::attribute(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" (?attribute@Image@Magick@@$$FQAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V34@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall UseLIB::Form1::btnStart_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?btnStart_Click@Form1@UseLIB@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)

Any advice will be most appreciated and thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be due to conflicting versions of ImageMagick on the one PC.  And make sure that MAGICK_CORE is set correctly in the environment variables.  Once I had that sorted out the program compiled, linked and executed OK.